# Is there a more efficient way to distribute non-zero elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Inputs: `array = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]` and `mid_space = 5`

Expected Output: `array = [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]`

Essentially I want to "respace" the ones such that there are `mid_space` number of zeroes between them and the remaining zeroes are equally spaced at the front and back.

My existing approach is:

1. to calculate the current spacing eg [3,4,3,9,4] and the expected_spacing [4,5,5,5,4]
2. then the difference between these two: [1,1,2,-4,0]
3. then insert a zero at the front, insert a zero after the next set of ones, insert 2 zeroes after the next set and so on.

I'm looking for a simpler and more efficient approach without using so much code as I would need to do here.

Any advice?

edit:
To calculate the expected_spacing I first calculate the total number of spaces (23 here), then the remaining spaces after allocating a group of 5 to each set of ones `23 - (5 * 3[which is the number of sets of "11"])` = 8.
Then This means that 8/2 = 4 on each of the start and end of the array.

Comment: Why are the opening and closing spaces 4?

Comment: Assuming I start with a given number of spaces. In this example there are only 23 spaces available so I need to "rebalance" the sets of ones given the only requirement of the mid_space. From the 23 if I take the mid_space for each set that would be 5+5+5 leaving 8 spaces. This is the 4 on either side

Comment: That makes sense. What if you don't have enough spaces? Or is `mid_space` a function of the number of spaces in the array?

Comment: In this example assume there will always be at least one space available/remaining to add to the front and the back

Comment: the real example that I'm dealing is very similar to this case. I'm hoping to find a simpler approach for this and then extrapolate to my real world situation

Comment: Are the groups of 1s always made up of two 1s? Or can that vary?

Comment: Are you looking to mutate the input array, or to produce a new array?

Comment: always two ones in a set

Comment: happy to produce a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not about efficiency in terms of perf but in terms of sweating

You can simply manipulate strings

- truncate the leading/trailing zeros
- replace any group of 0 by 5 zeros
- complete the string on both start and end with appropriate zeros

```js
const v = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
const s = 
  v.join('')
  .replace(/0/g,' ').trim() // skip leading/trailing zeros
  .replace(/ +/g, '00000')   // replace any groups of zeros
const n = Math.floor((v.length - s.length) / 2) // we assume there is at least one zero to be added, otherwise check for negativeness
const v2 = ('0'.repeat(n) + s + '0'.repeat(v.length - s.length - n)
  ).split('').map(x => parseInt(x))
console.log('bef', v.join(''))
console.log('aft', v2.join(''))
```

edit: floored n as spotted by @trincot, thx

Comment: removing spacing before defaulting to mid_space = brilliant!

Comment: If the input has one less 0, then the output does not have the same length as the input. Instead of `/ 2` do `>> 1`.

Comment: @trincot not sure what is the intended goal of >> 1. If it is about flooring, then repeat does so anyway. If it is about handling negative cases (as adding 5 zeros leads to a bigger string than original) then it's undefined behaviour because out of op's scope. Maybe you are addressing an other case, if you could clarify that'd be helpful to me, thx

Comment: I ran your snippet with  `v` having one zero less at the end. Check the results...

Comment: thx @trincot . missed the fact that I was using repeat twice!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a solution that does not perform conversion to string, which comes with a performance impact:

```js
function spread(array, midSpace) {
    let splitCount = 0, i = -2;
    while ((i = array.indexOf(1, i+2)) != -1) splitCount++;
    // Fill the result array with only zeroes
    let result = Array(array.length).fill(0);
    // Then populate the 1-values at the right spots
    for (let i = (array.length - splitCount * (midSpace + 2) + midSpace) >> 1; splitCount; splitCount--, i += midSpace) {
        result[i++] = 1;
        result[i++] = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

let input = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0];
console.log(String(spread(input, 5)));
```

In my tests this performed a couple of times faster than the solution that manipulates strings. The script I used for benchmarking is attached.

```js
function spreadTrincot(array, midSpace) {
    let splitCount = 0, i = -2;
    while ((i = array.indexOf(1, i+2)) != -1) splitCount++;
    // Fill the result array with only zeroes
    let result = Array(array.length).fill(0);
    // Then populate the 1-values at the right spots
    for (let i = (array.length - splitCount * (midSpace + 2) + midSpace) >> 1; splitCount; splitCount--, i += midSpace) {
        result[i++] = 1;
        result[i++] = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

function spreadGrodzi(v, midSpace) {
    const s = 
      v.join('')
      .replace(/0/g,' ').trim() // skip leading/trailing zeros
      .replace(/ +/g, '0'.repeat(midSpace));   // replace any groups of zeros
    const n = Math.floor((v.length - s.length) / 2); // we assume there is at least one zero to be added, otherwise check for negativeness
    const v2 = ('0'.repeat(n) + s + '0'.repeat(v.length - s.length - n)
      ).split('').map(x => parseInt(x));
    return v2;
}

const delay = (ms=10) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const asyncLog = msg => Promise.resolve(console.log(msg)).then(delay);

(async () => {
  let times = 50000;
  let input = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0];
  input = input.concat(input);
  input = input.concat(input);
  input = input.concat(input);
  input = input.concat(input);
  input = input.concat(input); // make input longer.
  let result, result2, start, delay;

  await asyncLog("input size is " + input.length);

  await asyncLog("calling trincot's function...");
  start = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) result = spreadTrincot(input, 5);
  delay = performance.now() - start;
  await asyncLog("trincot's function finishes in " + delay + "ms");

  await asyncLog("calling grodzi's function...");
  start = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) result2 = spreadGrodzi(input, 5);
  delay = performance.now() - start;
  await asyncLog("grodzi's function finishes in " + delay + "ms");

  await asyncLog("Check that outputs are same: " + (result+"" == result2+""));
})();
```